# How can I remove automatic image resizing in Opencart 2.3.0.2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I've been looking everywhere for a fix that would remove automatic image resizing done on product images by OpenCart. A lot of the fixes that work for older versions don't work for 2.3.0.2 (usually are edits of image.php) and the only thing I've found for 2.3.0.2 was a VQmod that for whatever reason didn't work for me, even after clearing out VQcache.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**In this file:**

```
catalog/model/tool/image.php
```

**Find:**

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

**Add before it:**

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $filename;
} else {
    return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $filename;
}
```